# Can I change object owner in Oracle 21c XE?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle21c

I want to change the object (table) owner to the system, but I did not get any information about this change by looking it up on Google.

How do I change the object owner?

Oracle database version is 21c Express Edition Release 21.0.0.0.0.

Also, can I not view a table created by a common user unless privileges are granted, even if the 'sys' user?

Best regards,
Woogie.

Comment: To SYSTEM? As username? One of *special* users in an Oracle database? Why would you want to do that? There's rarely valid reason to do anything in SYSTEM schema.

Comment: Object owner in Oracle is the same as table schema, which cannot be changed without recreation. This seems to be XY Problem, because you would never want to set `system` as table owner. Please, describe what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object ownership cannot be changed in Oracle. The object must be recreated.

`sys` should be able to see anything within the currently connected database context (CDB or individual PDB). Other users will require either explicit grants on the table, or a system privilege like `select any table` granted within the CDB or individual PDB where the table is located.

Update: Also note that the `system` account is only a template DBA/privileged account provided by Oracle. It should *never* own application objects or code. Always put application objects in dedicated (and relatively unprivileged) application schemas.